# Flask как заставить работать модальное окно

Tags: jquery, flask

Возникла такая проблема. Написано вроде все правильно, но метод не срабатывает.
Вот код.

**user.html**

```
<tbody>
   {% for user in users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ user.nickname }} </td>
                                <td> {{ user.email }}</td>
                                <td> {{ user.password }}</td>
                                <td> {{ user.is_admin }}</td>
                                <td>

                                    <a class="modal-link" href="{{url_for('admin.delete_user', id = user.id)}}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
```

В шаблоне вроде все прописал, вот так выглядит низ шаблона

```
<script src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/static/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/static/scripts/respond.js"></script>

{% block scripts %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            });

            $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            });
            $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });

            $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
                return false;
            });
        });
        });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Причем убираю скрипт вызова модельного окна, как все начинает работать, но только без модального окна.

Вот сам метод

```
@admin.route('/delete_user/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def delete_user(id):
    print(id)
    user = User.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
    print(user)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("admin/_modal.html", user=user)

    return jsonify(status='ok')
```

Я его еще не дописал, но метод get для вызова модального окна достаточно. Не могу понять в чем проблема, при клике по кнопке ничего не происходит.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память то шаблонизатор и JS конфликтуют между собой, попробуйте вынести JS в отдельный файл.

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko Попробывал, но ничего не поменялось. Дело в том, что скрипт отрабатывает, но запрос GET не идет.

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko  Сделал вот так     <script src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{

    url_for('static', filename='modal.js') }}"></script>